# Incomplete spelling of vii dim7 and vii half dim7

Tags: theory, piano, harmony, keyboard, functional-harmony

For the two chords above, diminished 7th (viio7) and half diminished 7th (viiø7), are they usually spelled complete or incomplete? Or both?

Comment: Spelled or played? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah, one or the other.

Comment: usually the *half dim7* is notated and spelt  as 7 b5

Comment: Can anyone explain the confusion between whether OP meant spelled or played? It seems to me they *only* used the term "spell," yet *never* used the term "play."

Answer (score 1):

First, I’m sorry your question got a downvote. It is a bit unclear what you’re asking but better to ask for clarity than do that. I will give you some information that hopefully will give you what you’re looking for.

You probably know both chords start with a diminished triad, R, b3 and b5. From there the diminished chord has a bb7 (same as a M6) and the half diminished a b7. For the vii in the key of C that would be:

B diminished: B D F Ab

B half diminished: B D F A

Now when you say “spelled”, regardless of whether these chords are spelled/written out or played it is necessary to include all their notes. The reason for this is that every note in both these chords plays an important part in their makeup and by having an incomplete spelling the chord either becomes ambiguous or even a completely different chord. For example, if you leave out the b3 is it a major or minor chord? Leave out the b5 and you won’t know if it’s diminished or not. Omit the 7th from either one and it is just a diminished triad.

There are some group playing situations where a pianist might omit the root from his chord voicing but if he does it would typically be played by the bass to complete the chord.

Comment: I have seen chords with the function of vii°7 but missing an inner note.

Answer (score 0):

usually the half dim7 (ti,re,fa,la) is notated and spelt as (Chordletter) and 7 ♭5,
while vii dim7 = vii°7

Roman number: vii7 in major is half diminished (=ii in minor).
The viidim7 or vii°7 in major borrowed from the minor parallel key is identical with vii7 in minor from where it is derived: ti,re,fa,lu => si,ti,re,fa. also the  as a secondary vii°7 to the dominant chord (fi,la,do,ma = #IV°7) -> V.

Answer (score 0):

> are they usually spelled complete or incomplete?

I think first we need to say *why* certain chord tones can be omitted. Some progressions like...

[image]

...can involve omissions but the harmony will still be clear. Both are clearly dominant to tonic and major mode even though all the chords are incomplete. Consider the tonic chord, for example, you don't really need to play the fifth, because whether it's major or minor key the fifth of the tonic will be the same.

The two diminished chords don't really work the same way, because in order to distinguish them from each other and other chords you really need all the tones.

First, you must have the seventh. It's literally the tone defining them as seventh chords.

Same thing goes for the fifth. In order for these chords to have their diminished quality they must have the diminished fifth.

Generally you don't omit the third from a chord and the same goes with these diminished chords.

It seems like it should be said that you could omit certain tones and the harmony could still work, but it could imply other, simpler chords.

Also, there is a certain aural quality to these seventh chords that you only get when they are complete. A diminished seventh chord and half diminished chord have distinctive "sounds", certain tremulous qualities you simply will not get if the chords are not complete.

So, major and minor triads can be incomplete, but diminished and half-diminished seventh chords really need to be fully voiced.

Answer (score 0):

Composers of all periods frequently leave chords of all varieties incomplete for any number of reasons, but most often for voice-leading.